# Promise always return "undefined" in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

I'm trying to pass data using http.get from a JSON to other component, but always I get a "undefined"

In my service.ts I have the getDate function

```
getData(): Promise<MinnanoNihongo[]>{
   return this.http.get("../../assets/json/leccion1.json")
          .toPromise()
          .then(response => response.json().data as MinnanoNihongo[]);
}
```

And in my component I call using:

```
this.MinnaData
         .getData()
         .then( data => this._Minna = data );
    console.log(this._Minna);  //show Undefined in console
```

I'm new using Angular and typescript so I don't know what produce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `console.log(this._Minna);` is executed before `.then( data => this._Minna = data );`

Try

```
this.MinnaData
         .getData()
         .then( data => this._Minna = data ).then(() => {
             console.log(this._Minna)
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should print console.log inside then

```
this.MinnaData
         .getData()
         .then( (data) => {this._Minna = data;
          console.log(this._Minna);
 });
```

Comment: this make me an error " ')' expected "

Comment: @user1553471 check the updated one

Comment: now don't show errors, but still showing "undefined"